# uninitialized constant SitePrism from page declariation

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

I'm trying to set up a basic framework using Capybara, Cucumber and SitePrism, but I keep getting the error, "uninitialized constant SitePrism (NameError)" when I kick off a test.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'cucumber', '2.3.3'
gem 'capybara', '2.6.2'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.53.0'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'site_prism'
gem 'mime-types', '>2.6', '<2.99.1'
```

Env.rb

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'site_prism'
require 'cucumber'

require_rel '../features/pages'
require_rel '../features/classes'

World(Capybara::DSL)
World(Capybara::RSpecMatchers)
```

Login page

```
class LoginPage < SitePrism::Page
end
```

Login class

```
class Login

def initialize
  @current_page = LoginPage.new
end
```

The error is being thrown on the line with "class LoginPage < SitePrism::Page". RubyMine can't find the SitePrism declaration to go to either. Am I missing something in the setup?

Answer (score 1):

Your error looks 'require' related, but here is how I got it to work via:
https://github.com/thuss/standalone-cucumber

Haven't used cucumber in a while, but the way I see "pages" currently implemented in my Rails project:

- Create a file in "features/support/pages"
- Follow the namespace conventions
- Use modules, then import via the World() method.

Maybe this might work:

features/support/pages/login_page.rb

```
module Pages
 module LoginPage

  class LoginPageObj < SitePrism::Page
  end

  def login_obj
   LoginPageObj.new
  end

 end
end
World(Pages::LoginPage)
```

Env file:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'site_prism'


Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.default_driver = :selenium
  config.app_host   = 'http://www.google.com'
end

World(Capybara::DSL)
World(Capybara::RSpecMatchers)
```

Notice how I didn't have to explicitly require any pages class, it looks like Cucumber might require it for you?

- Note this is without RubyMine (I dont use it). If it works without RubyMine, I'd point fingers to that.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked. I also found that I was missing the require_all gem. My final solution was to move the folders and have the require_all gem installed.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason you were getting this problem is because of the files being auto-loaded. Just ensure you `require` the gem files first so the namespaces are understood